# Overriding default locale in strptime()

Tags: r

I have date variables in the following format: `"01OCT2018"`. I would like the output to be in the following format: `"2018-10-01"`. In the documentation of `strptime()` it says that `%b` is the "abbreviated month name in the current locale". Therefore, since my default locale is de_DE_UTF-8 (Germany), I get the following:

```
strptime("01OCT2018", format = "%d%b%Y") # NA

strptime("01OKT2018", format = "%d%b%Y") # "2018-10-01 GMT"
```

However, changing my locale using `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", locale = "en_US_UTF-8")` does not change the results of the above calls. Is there any other way I can override the default locale or maybe an even simpler solution to my problem?

Comment: did you try `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")`?

Comment: Thanks, now it works! I was trying `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", locale = "en_US_UTF-8")`.

Comment: You also have error in your syntax. You should replace `&` with `%`

Comment: Thanks, I edited that in the question since I didn't have that typo in my original code. It was just a typo when I was writing the question here on SO.