# Problem to convert string with month abbreviation to POSIXlt

Tags: r, datetime, posixlt

I tried to convert Excel date character to date-time class using `POSIXlt`. This is an example of my data: `"01:56:00 06-Apr-2017"`.

For the `format`, I used the character string giving a date-time format as used by `strptime`.

I tried `as.POSIXlt(new_dtime, format = "%H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y")`, but it resulted in a bunch of `NA`. I am sure that the problem is related to the month abbreviation, despite I used  `%b` as `strptime` suggests. Any help?

Comment: Baed on your example, I get `str1 <- "01:56:00 06-Apr-2017"; as.POSIXct(str1, format = "%H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y")
[1] "2017-04-06 01:56:00 EDT"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess that this is a locale problem: from `?strptime`, `%b` denotes "[a]bbreviated month name **in the current locale on this platform**" (emphasis added). "Apr" is the abbreviation for April in an English locale.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016614/overriding-default-locale-in-strptime) suggests the following solution:

```
str1 <- "01:56:00 06-Apr-2017" 
orig_locale <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
as.POSIXct(str1, format = "%H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", orig_locale)
```

Comment: It worked! thanks a lot :)